# NSTableView - Disable Row Selection

Tags: cocoa, selection, nstableview

I have a `NSTableView` and I want to disable row selection.

The columns of the table view are bound to a `NSArrayController` and the content of the array does show up in the table view.

How can I do this just using `bindings`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you'll need to use a TableViewDelegate and implement

```
- (NSIndexSet *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
    selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:(NSIndexSet *)proposedSelectionIndexes
```

Answer (score 23):

While the previous answers work, this is another option which I prefer to use:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the method you'd want if you want to disable some rows and not others from being selected

Answer (score 13):

I think

```
- (BOOL)selectionShouldChangeInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
  return NO;
}
```

is better than

```
- (NSIndexSet *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:(NSIndexSet *)proposedSelectionIndexes
```

Comment: You can read in the header file: "For better performance and better control over the selection, you should use tableView:selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:."

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4.0**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a note to posterity...

If you declare selectionIndexesForProposedSelection, then shouldSelectRow function will be ignored. Just in case you're wondering like I did why my edits to shouldSelectRow had no effect...

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:

Answer (score 1):

Using Binding:

Another approach is select 'empty' in the list of checkboxes corresponding to 'Selection' in Attribute Inspector of table view. This will not select any rows by default.

In addition to this, make the highlight option to 'None'.

[screenshot of attribute inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTuaP.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Binding:**

In case of binding, you can bind a boolean value with Enabled.
[binding inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frPZS.png)

if the value in sample is true, it would be selectable or else, it wouldnt be.
This way, we dont need to use delegates just for disabling selection when all other stuffs are done through binding.

Answer (score 0):

[image]> Through this by default TableView selection remove from bind inspector

[image]

[image]